# db2 can't start, SQL1220N The database manager shared memory set cannot be allocated

Tags: memory, db2, shared

Before I tried to change instances and groups, I can start db2 with writing on command line: "db2start". But after my changes about these group and instance issues I can not start db2 database and I get an error like "SQL1220N The database manager shared memory set cannot be allocated" . It's weird because , It used to work but now I can't make it work. I tried lots of way like db2ftok, instance automatic... Still it isn't working. How can I fix this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Undo whatever changes you did. Then explain why you did them/what you're trying to achieve and maybe someone can help you doing that correctly.

Answer (score 1):

What OS you are running this on? This usually happens when your system is not DB2 enough memory to db2 instance ID. There are two ways to handle this

1. Check the OS memory and make sure you have enough memory allocated.
2. Reduce the memory for DB2. If automatic doesn't work - set it to a hard value.